# Problem using async and await functionality while connecting to mysql db

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, async-await

I am trying to write a retry logic for connecting a TS application with AWS Aurora DB for mysql.
To wake the serverless db, I am retrying to connect to the db 3 times after waiting for 55, 34 and 21 seconds.

To simulate this behavior on my local machine, I have changed the port number of mysql server and while doing that I am getting a valid error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3305`.

The issue is, I am getting this error immediately after I execute `await createDb('dbName')` of `Database` class. The retry logic I have written is not working. It should retry to connect to the server 3 times taking at least 55+34+21 seconds.

What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
@injectable()
export class Database {
    private readonly databaseConnectionFactory: DatabaseConnectionFactory;
     
    constructor(@inject(Identifiers.DatabaseConnectionFactory) databaseConnectionFactory: DatabaseConnectionFactory){
         this.databaseConnectionFactory = databaseConnectionFactory;
    }

    public async createDb(dbName: string): Promise<any> {
        console.log('dbconnection before');
        let dbConnection  = await this.databaseConnectionFactory.getDbConnection();
        console.log('dbconnection after');

        let sql = `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${dbName};`;
        dbConnection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                throw err; // Throwing the error here.
            }
            console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            dbConnection.end();
        });
    }
} 

@injectable()
export class DatabaseConnectionFactory {
    private readonly configParams: ConfigParams;
     
    constructor(@inject(Identifiers.ConfigParams) configParams: ConfigParams){
         this.configParams = configParams;
    }

    public async getDbConnection(attempt: number = 1): Promise<any> {
        try {
            let dbConnection  = mysql.createConnection({
                host: 'mysqlHost',
                port: 3305,
                user: 'mysqlUser',
                password: 'mysqlPassword',
            });
            
            dbConnection.connect(async function(err) {
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                } 
                console.log("Connected!");
            });
            return dbConnection;
        } catch (err){
            console.log('attempt');
            console.log(attempt);
            switch(attempt){
                case 1: {
                    console.log('before wait');
                    await this.wait(55);
                    console.log('after wait');
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    await this.wait(34);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    await this.wait(21);
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    throw err;
                }
            }

            await this.getDbConnection(attempt + 1);
        }
    }

    private async wait(seconds: number): Promise<any> {
        const ms = 1000 * seconds;
        console.log('wait');
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of your `console.log()` calls are you seeing?

Comment: `dbConnection.connect(async function(err) {` is not how async await works

Comment: You need to look into promisifying callback based APIs. Your functions are declared as returning Promises but aren't creating promises or returning them.

Comment: Also. If the connect fails, any subsequent succesful attempt will not return a connection anyway

Comment: @Pointy I am getting console logs for dbconnection before and after but console.log('attempt'), console.log('before wait') and console.log('after wait') are not printing.

Comment: @ChrisG How can I do that? Please share a reference.

Comment: Here's a promisified setTimeout: https://jsfiddle.net/k19qg43p/ (note how the function that returns the Promise is not async because it doesn't await anything, it only constructs a Promise and returns it)